# Consume CommonJS Module Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, commonjs, systemjs

I'm trying to write a simple Angular 2 application which consumes a CommonJS Node module ([Node Yelp](https://github.com/olalonde/node-yelp)). Angular 2 by default uses [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) which has the ability to load different module formats.

I have tried several different SystemJS configurations and import statements, but all of them seem to end with

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)

Currently, my SystemJS configuration looks like

```
System.config({
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    },
    map: {
        yelp: 'node_modules/yelp'
    }
});

System.import('app/main')
    .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

and my simple `AppComponent.ts`

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import Yelp from 'yelp';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: '/app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(yelp: Yelp) {
        console.log(yelp);
    }
}
```

I'm still trying to wrap my head around the whole module system, so I'm not exactly sure what to change here. Any results online seem to be out dated, or not direclty related to loading CommonJS node modules with SystemJS.

Comment: That error usually happens because your server returns index.html if requested path isn't found... Check DevTools>Network and see what file (path) systemjs is trying to load.

Comment: @Sasxa Ah, good call. It seems SystemJS isn't traversing the package correctly. It isn't picking up index.js by default then when I hard code it, it doesn't know to look in `node_modules` for the packages dependencies.

Comment: Try with [`meta`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#meta) option, it supports wildcards

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could try something like that:

```
System.config({
  packages: {
    app: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    },
    yeld: {
      main: index.js
    }
  },
  map: {
    yelp: 'node_modules/yelp'
  }
});
```

and

```
import * as Yelp from 'yelp';
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that and it seems to pick up the module, but then can't seem to resolve any of it's dependencies, OAuth and querystring in this case. It just goes back to looking at the root of the application. This is even with `format: 'cjs'` specified.

Comment: It seems that the path can't be found (404). The "true" error behind: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <(…)`. Is this path reachable: `node_modules/yelp/index.js`?

Comment: Yes, it loads `node_modules/yelp/index.js`, then picks up the fact that it's simply a container module and loads `node_modules/yelp/lib/index.js`, but then `lib/index.js` has `require` for `OAuth` and `querystring` which SystemJS cannot seem to resolve because it is looking in the application root directory instead of `node_modules/yelp/node_modules/OAuth/index.js` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, as I expected, turned out to be an easy one.

**Don't try roll your own `System.config` when using NPM packages in Angular 2**

Instead, use [jspm](http://jspm.io/) to install packages. By doing so, all of the `System.config` will be taken care of by jspm. In this particular case, it was as easy as

> jspm install npm:yelp

Then just adding

```
import Yelp from 'npm:yelp@1.0.1';
```

to the top of my `AppComponent.ts` file